# Iterative folder open, process and save image one by one

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, subdirectory, os.walk, directory-traversal

I have a folder "Images-2" which has more than 100 sub folders, these sub folders consist of one image per folder. `def main()` opens each image, and `def run(img)` takes the image and processes it, but now I am unable to save that image in it's sub folder.

e.g `def main` c:/Images-2/1/1.png (1 is the folder name, so I have 100 folders in Images-2)

**if condition** will save processed image(zero.png) in folder Images-2/1/

**How will it work for 100 folders, 1 image each folder?**

```
def run(img):
  data = img.load()
  width, height = img.size
  output_img = Image.new("RGB", (100, 100))
  Zero=np.zeros(shape=(100, 100),dtype=np.uint8)

  for (x, y) in labels:
            component = uf.find(labels[(x, y)])
            labels[(x, y)] = component
            path='C:/Python27/cclabel/Images-2/'
            if labels[(x, y)]==0:
                Zero[y][x]=int(255)
                Zeroth = Image.fromarray(Zero)
                for root, dirs in os.walk(path):
                    print root
                    print dirs
                    Zeroth.save(path+'Zero'+'.png','png')
def main():
    # Open the image
    path="C:/Python27/cclabel/Images-2/"
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for file_ in files:
            img = Image.open(os.path.join(root, file_))
            img = img.point(lambda p: p > 190 and 255)
            img = img.convert('1')
            (labels, output_img) = run(img)

if __name__ == "__main__": main()
```

Comment: Where is the variable `labels` in `run` defined? I would think that you should pass `root` to `run` and then remove the `os.walk` from `run` and just do `Zeroth.save(os.path.join(root, 'Zero.png'), 'png')` to store the “Zero” image into the same directory that you loaded the image from.

Comment: thats the issue i am unable to save it on right path it is just taking last folder image processed it and saving it on every folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `os.walk` twice. That is your problem. This is what I meant in my comment:

```
def run(dirname, img):
    data = img.load()
    width, height = img.size
    output_img = Image.new("RGB", (100, 100))
    Zero=np.zeros(shape=(100, 100), dtype=np.uint8)

    for (x, y) in labels:
        component = uf.find(labels[(x, y)])
        labels[(x, y)] = component
        path = 'C:/Python27/cclabel/Images-2/'
        if labels[(x, y)] == 0:
            Zero[y][x] = 255
            Zeroth = Image.fromarray(Zero)
            Zeroth.save(os.path.join(dirname, 'Zero.png'), 'png')


def main():
    path = "C:/Python27/cclabel/Images-2/"
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for file_ in files:
            img = Image.open(os.path.join(root, file_))
            img = img.point(lambda p: p > 190 and 255)
            img = img.convert('1')
            (labels, output_img) = run(root, img)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: The first one is just a mess up of parentheses, I fix that in my post. For the second comment: What do you mean? Could you please elaborate a bit?

Comment: This code worked fine for 6 folder traversing but after loading 100 more folders its not working. any idea  why?

Comment: Did it happen to stop after 1021 images perhaps? I would assume that `Image.open` has to be accompanied by an `Image.close(...)` or `img.close()`. The problem might be that you [run out of file descriptors](https://martin-ueding.de/articles/c-file-descriptors/index.html).

Comment: os.walk is working but very slow how i can replace it to any other